# A method which accepts two integer values as input parameters and returns the boolean

Tags: java, methods, int, boolean

This is one of the practice questions of a test:

> Write a method which accepts two integer values as input parameters and returns the boolean result `true` if the sum of the inputs is greater than or equal to 10 (and `false`otherwise)

My answer is below but I don't think it looks correct. Can anyone give me a pointer?

```
public class Bruh{
    public static void main (String [] arg){
        int a;
        int b;
        boolean sum = true;
        if ( a+b > 10)
          System.out.println ("yo");
        else{ 
            sum = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well no - you haven't created a method which accepts two integer values and returns a boolean. Hint: `public static boolean isSumGreaterThan10(int a, int b)`

Comment: You have no return statement, so it doesn't return anything. Next to that, greater or equal is >=, not > (this is just greater)

Comment: So is this what you meant?


public class Bruh{
  public static void main (String [] arg){
    
  }
  
  
  public static boolean greater(int a, int b, boolean sum){
    sum = true;
    
    if ( a+b >= 10)
      System.out.println ("yo");
    else{ 
      sum = false;
    }
  }
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only wrote some code in the `main` method but you did not create one.

In order to do that you need to actually create a method in your `Bruh` class like:

```
public static boolean isSumGreaterThan9(int a, int b){
    return (a + b) > 9;
}
```

Than call it from the `main` method:

```
public static void main (String [] arg){
    int a = 4; // or whatever
    int b = 7; // or whatever
    System.out.println(isSumGreaterThan9(a, b));
}
```

Comment: I don't wish to be pedantic but that method is checking greater than 9, not 10. It's a bit confusing if you were to do `isSumGreaterThan10(5, 5);` and have it return true.

Comment: @jonk the question states **Write a method which accepts two integer values as input parameters and returns the boolean result true if the sum of the inputs is greater than or equal to 10 (and falseotherwise)** so in case of `a + b = 10` `true` should be returned.

Comment: yes but your function is named `isSumGreaterThan10`, but then checks if sum is greater than 9, and as such will return true if sum is _equal_ to 10, hence it being confusing.

Comment: @jonk Yeah well I kinda used the signature suggested by Jon Skeet in hiss comment. Fixed...

Answer (score 1):

You need to put your logic into a method and change your comparison to `>=` as per the requirement:

```
public static boolean isSumGreaterThanOrEqualToTen(int a, int b) {
    return (a + b) >= 10;    
}
```